# How can I automatically convert a string to a number after I import it into Excel?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2013

I am downloading an xml file using PowerQuery into an Excel spreadsheet.  The download is fine, however, the data I am looking to use is coming across as a string (with a "General" datatype.

Is there some way to automatically convert it to a number, or to convert it to a number in a SUM formula, right now the basic =SUM(U2:U20) does not work (due to the fields being considered text.

The xml file will be downloaded several times a day by several people, so it I could put the solution directly into the spreadsheet itself that would be great.

Update
I have tried using the Value() function, specifically

```
=SUM(VALUE(U2:U20)) (returns #value)
```

as well as

```
=VALUE(SUM(U2:U20)) (returns zero)
```

As well as 
    =SUM(N(U2:U20)) (returns #value)
as well as

```
=N(SUM(U2:U20)) (returns zero)
```

It seems that the Value does not work in ranges - which you would think it would.

Comment: Value doesn't seem to do anything for summing a range though - I amended my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a formula `=Value()` to convert a text string that represents a number to a number.

Use `=IfError()` to handle errors in case of text that can't be converted.

Another option is to use `=N()` to convert text to numbers. Using this formula, if it can't convert to a number it will return 0. See [N Formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/n-function-HP010062398.aspx) for more info.

These formulas only work for a single cell. So if you have a column of numbers as text you would need a column of =Value() to convert each cell individually. Then use =Sum() on the results of the second column.

Comment: I amended my question to clarify - value and n don't seem to work.

Comment: Hmmm, is there a way to automatically create the =Value() column?  The tricky part is that all of these things are automatically imported, so I think certain things get columns get destroyed and recreated

Comment: Sure you can using VBA.

Comment: Actually a better way is to just create a separate column in another sheet with the =Value(OriginjalSheet!U9) in every column, and working off of that.  Marking as answered - thank you very much

Comment: You can skip the helper column by using an array formula: `=SUM(VALUE(U2:U20))`, entered with `ctrl+shift+enter` instead of plain `enter`. This converts the range U2:U20 to an array, evaluates `value` on each element (since `value` accepts only single values) then sums to a single value (since `sum` accepts arrays). There's also a common hack, using `sumproduct` with single argument in place of `sum` (eg`=SUMPRODUCT(VALUE(U2:U20))`) to avoid typing `ctrl+shift+enter`. `sumproduct` accepts *only* arrays, so it converts range expressions to array expressions. Not a fan myself, but won't judge:-)

Answer (score 0):

Type "1" (without quotes) in an unused cell of your spreadsheet. Copy that cell.
Select a range containing downloaded data. From right mouse click menu choose 'Paste Special'
and select paste: values and operation: multiply.

This operation should convert data to numbers, so not only you can sum it up but also sort it numerically if necessary.

Of course you can use a macro to automate process:

```
Sub Macro1()
  Range("J18").Value = 1
  Range("J18").Copy
  Range("K1:K6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlMultiply
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```